# Questions about $|f(1+a+bi)|<|f(1+a)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Let $a,b >0$ and $|*|$ denote the absolute value. Let $f(z)$ be a realvalued analytic function defined for $Re(z)>1.$ For any $a,b$ we have $|f(1+a+bi)|<|f(1+a)|$.

Some questions :

$1)$ If $f(z)$ has meromorphic continuation to $Re(z)>0$ and no poles at $f(c)$ for any $0<c<1$ , does that imply

$|f(a+bi)|<|f(a)|$ ?

$2)$ Let $c_n$ be a sequence of positive reals. Is every $f(z)$ of the form $c_1 + \sum_{n>1} \dfrac{c_n}{n^z}$ ?

If not, what are the counterexamples ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I believe a real-valued analytic function cannot meet the requirement, as it's necessarily constant.

Comment: @JonathanY. With realvalued is meant mapping R -> R.

Comment: Thanks. Also, did you mean $\sum\frac{c_n}{z^n}$? Should we start the indices from $n=1$? Else, $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: It seems a counterexample yes ! @JonathanY.